# How to move down 1 row after scanning bar code

Tags: microsoft-excel, barcode

I am not a professional in the use of Excel and need some help.

The cursor moves down 1 row after scanning barcode & hit the enter key.

How does it move 1 row down without hitting the enter key? Is there any VBA code for it?

Comment: This is usually something you have to change in the barcodescanner itself

Comment: I think you're asking how to send the enter key, but I can't be sure... in VBA you can use `vbCr` and/or `vbLf`

Answer (score 2):

Your barcode scanner works like a keyboard, this way it can be used with virtually any application. It apparently doesn't send any character or sequence that would be interpreted as a newline. Many (most? all?) scanners can be configured to send [CR or LF or CR+LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) or none; usually by simply scanning one of few special barcodes.

Refer to the manual specific to your scanner. The special barcodes may be there; or they may be printed on a separate chart. The manual may reveal an alternative way to configure the scanner.

Comment: Most barcode scanners can work with form field control characters, but be aware that Windows vs other platforms have different EOL conventions.  Also, be very careful when using barcodes to alter the scanner settings as there are known exploits that target this exact action.  When accessing manuals/instructions, make sure to verify (OEM or other reputable source).